# Q: Have Scroll & On Click on a Single Screen in Framer

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, user-experience, framerjs

I'm trying to recreate iChat in Framer.js. I'm stuck because I can't figure out how to do a scroll and on click on a single screen. I'm trying to mimic the main messages screen on iChat where you can see all your messages, then you can click into an image to view it in its entirety. When you set a scroll component on an image, it overrides a click event.

Here's where I am currently (granted this is a very basic interactive wireframe): http://share.framerjs.com/rrfcftx09hpv/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue not long ago.
You can resolve your problem using this trick :

```
yourButton.on Events.Click, ->
    unless yourScrollComponent.isMoving
        /* your actions */
```

Hope it will be helpful :)